# Wildfly 26.1.1 + keycloak 18 + OIDC sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal() returns anonymous

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, wildfly-26

We are moving to Wildfly 26 from v.22. Using Keycloak v18 for authentication.

I switched from keycloak adapter to openid-connect/OIDC following
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-security/secure-wildfly-applications-with-openid-connect/

After login I get org.wildfly.security.http.oidc.OidcSecurityContext as http request attribute and I can see an authenticated user name and the roles.

But when I inject `@Resource SessionContext` in Stateless bean, `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()` is returned as `org.wildfly.security.auth.principal.AnonymousPrincipal`. Keycloak adapter used to return a `KeycloakPrincipal` with full info.

Any other configuration needed to propagate security to EJB level?

Might be similar to [Wildfly 26.1.0 final + elytron-oidc-client + wont propagate user to EJB + user become anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075843/wildfly-26-1-0-final-elytron-oidc-client-wont-propagate-user-to-ejb-user-b)   but I have everyting in a single WAR - just a servlet and a Stateless bean

Thanks

Comment: did you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the EJB is part of the same deployment, the identity will be propagated. However, the EJB does need to be secured (i.e., it needs to have a security annotation).

Comment: i did this using @SecurityDomain(value = "other"). Then i get "not allowed". Adding PermittAll results to the same, having annonymous principal. Do i need to add something like a "token-realm" to elytron configuration or should this work out of the box ?

Comment: No need to specify the "other" SecurityDomain on the EJB, that's different from the virtual security domain that is used by the elytron-oidc-client subsystem. As long as your EJB is secured (i.e., has a security annotation), the identity propagation should work.